# Let $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y=X²-1$. Show that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated but not independent.

Tags: random-variables, correlation

I've got some problems with the following task:

Let $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y=X²-1$. Show that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated but not independent. I showed that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated but I'm not sure how to proof the dependence of $X$ and $Y$. Can anybody give me some hints?
I calculated the density function of $Y$ but could not see, how this could help.

Comment: hint: $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are uncorrelated for all functions $f,g$ such that $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are square integrable.

Comment: Think about, say, $P(Y<0)$ vs. $P( Y<0 | X > 1)$. Can you see that these numbers must be unequal?

Comment: Ned's answer will help you determine independence. Use the formula for correlation and show the result is $0$ to show uncorrelated.